# Can I make the height of an element grow dynamically once a column flexbox container starts to overflow?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to make a 3 column layout for a part of an interface. I am using flexbox to lay it out since I can use `flex-direction: column` and let it keep moving to the right. Each content box is a width of 30%, which will ideally give me the 3 columns I am looking for. The problem I am having is when the content grows too big for the container vertically, it begins to overflow in the x-direction.

See this codepen for an example of what I am trying to avoid: https://codepen.io/jtris1/pen/RwBZPNp

I tried setting the `min-height` of the content container to `100%`, but this results in it creating a single column down the container instead of the 3 I need. I also tried setting max-width on the container to see if it would force the content down, but the content still overflows in the x-direction.

HTML

```
<div className='guideline-detail-overlay-container'>
    <div className="overlay-info">
        <h2>Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div className='overlay-flex-content'>
        <div className="overlay-demographics overlay-content-box">
            <h3>Demographics</h3>
            ...
        </div>
        <div className="overlay-med-history overlay-content-box">
            <h3>Medical History</h3>
            ...
        </div>
        <div className="overlay-family-history overlay-content-box">
            <h3>Family History</h3>
            ...
        </div>
        <div className="overlay-services overlay-content-box">
            <h3>Preventative Screening Services</h3>
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.guideline-detail-overlay-container {
    /* display: none; */
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 2rem 4rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.overlay-flex-content {
    min-height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
}

.overlay-content-box {
    width: 30%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
}

.overlay-info {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice that when you use a 100% height you're assign the same height that the div (guideline-detail-overlay-container) **parent**. Change the height to auto should fix your problem. You also should delete height property.

```
guideline-detail-overlay-container {
 height : auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While *Flexbox Layout* is an easy way to define grids, sometimes it is even easier to use the 'older' CSS `columns` mechanism to *flow* a text.

- Define a parent *columns* container (`.guideline-detail-overlay-container`)
- Define the preferred maximum the number of columns it should hold.
- Define the preferred width of a single column. This value will resize with the width of the viewport and serves as a trigger to wrap content elements and to calculate whether there is enough room given the number of columns required.

I have disabled all *Flexbox Layout* related properties in your CSS code, inserted *columns layout* alternatives and commented the CSS and left the original code in-place for comparison.

**snippet**

```css
/* * { outline: 1px dashed } /* for debugging */


/* Set for all elements */
*, ::before, ::after { box-sizing: border-box }

.guideline-container {
  /*  position: relative; /* obsolete, has no use */
  /*  min-height: 70vh; /* obsolete, content will stretch the parent */
  /*  justify-content: center; /* obsolete, not a flexbox container */
}

.guideline-detail-overlay-container {
  /* display: none; */
  /*  position: absolute; /* obsolete, has no use */
  padding: 2rem 4rem;

  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid black;

/* obsolete, stretching is automatic
  width : 100%; 
  height: 100%;
*/
}

.overlay-flex-content {
  /* Set default required columns and column width (wrap trigger) */
  columns: 3 250px;
  /* 'columns' mechanism will differentiate on viewport resize */

/*  height: 100%; /* obsolete, stretched by content */
/*
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
*/
}

.overlay-content-box {
  /*
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
*/
}

.overlay-content-box:first-child>h3 {
  /* To remove jagged top of first item in first column */
  /* A well know issue */
  margin-top: 0;
}

.overlay-info {
  column-span: all;
  /*  width: 100%;  /* obsolete, handled by 'column-span' */
  /*  height: auto; /* obsolete, HTML default */
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='guideline-container'>
  <div class='guideline-detail-overlay-container'>
    <div class="overlay-info">
      <h2>Title</h2>
    </div>
    <div class='overlay-flex-content'>
      <div class="overlay-demographics overlay-content-box">
        <h3>Demographics</h3>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis possimus iure deserunt explicabo quasi quis aliquam vitae reiciendis nisi dignissimos obcaecati animi iusto cumque eum a, voluptate nesciunt assumenda corrupti?
      </div>
      <div class="overlay-med-history overlay-content-box">
        <h3>Medical History</h3>
        Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Odio, dolorem reprehenderit. Saepe sunt, aut ratione quasi quaerat voluptatum, iste, fugiat autem dolor velit exercitationem blanditiis nisi. Et in odio ducimus.
      </div>
      <div class="overlay-family-history overlay-content-box">
        <h3>Family History</h3>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut, neque cumque voluptatem adipisci nemo harum, hic dolorem accusamus, pariatur debitis velit est rem doloremque. Laboriosam ad corrupti sit excepturi suscipit.
      </div>
      <div class="overlay-services overlay-content-box">
        <h3>Preventative Screening Services</h3>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sit expedita saepe architecto quaerat beatae repellendus! Enim natus, totam quaerat officia non voluptatibus facilis, maiores molestias quos quam voluptates mollitia. Quae!
      </div>
      <div class="overlay-services overlay-content-box">
        <h3>Preventative Screening Services</h3>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sit expedita saepe architecto quaerat beatae repellendus! Enim natus, totam quaerat officia non voluptatibus facilis, maiores molestias quos quam voluptates mollitia. Quae!
      </div>
      <div class="overlay-services overlay-content-box">
        <h3>Preventative Screening Services</h3>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sit expedita saepe architecto quaerat beatae repellendus! Enim natus, totam quaerat officia non voluptatibus facilis, maiores molestias quos quam voluptates mollitia. Quae!
      </div>
      <div class="overlay-services overlay-content-box">
        <h3>Preventative Screening Services</h3>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Sit expedita saepe architecto quaerat beatae repellendus! Enim natus, totam quaerat officia non voluptatibus facilis, maiores molestias quos quam voluptates mollitia. Quae!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```